# Parent Child Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to call a function to bind a grid view of parent page on closing event of child page.

Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by child page, a page which is opened with window.open or a page which is opened in an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then I had a similar requirement to this a while ago.  Have a look at this page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13358/Refresh-a-GridView-control-on-the-parent-page-from.  I found it useful at the time.  If I have not understood your question then let me know and I will modify my answer.